# prepend filename, not destination path, using mv

Tags: bash, rename, mv

In the process of posting this question I've been experimenting with my code, I've come up with something that works, but my restless intellect wants to be a better programmer, not just solve the problem at hand, so I'm posting Script 1.0 and Script 1.1 to ask the community, **Why does the change to line 3 make it work?**

I'm copying files from a server and renaming them. The copying is going fine; the renaming isn't. These filenames have spaces. `cp` handles them competently; `mv` seems throws an error. I expected putting `""` around the variable name to resolve the issue, but it still gives an error: `mv: rename /src/foo.wav to zzz - /dest/foo.wav - copied 201403261800.wav: No such file or directory`. I'm trying to prepend "zzz" to the filename, but it's getting prepended to the destination path. Here's **Script 1.0:**

```
cd /src/
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" | while read file ; do
    if [[ "$file" != *zzz* ]]; then
        echo "Tranferring...";
        cp "$file" /dest/
        mv "$file" \zzz\ \-\ "$file"\ \-\ copied\ $DATE.wav
        echo "Transfer complete.";
    fi
done
```

(The `if` condition ensures that I don't re-copy anything I've previously copied and renamed.)

Changing the 3rd line makes it work. But why? Here's **Script 1.1:**

```
cd /src/
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
find *.* -iname "*.wav" | while read file ; do
    if [[ "$file" != *zzz* ]]; then
        echo "Tranferring...";
        cp "$file" /dest/
        mv "$file" \zzz\ \-\ "$file"\ \-\ copied\ $DATE.wav
        echo "Transfer complete.";
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output of the different `find` commands you'll see that `find . -type f` will return lines like this: `./passwd`.
Now you can't use that as the target, as renaming `./passwd` to `zzz - ./passwd` would try to move it to a `zzz - .` folder as `passwd`.

By the way, you can surround the whole target name with quotes, to make it look better (also you should not escape the first z anyway):

```
mv "$file" "zzz - $file - copied $DATE.wav"
```

Also you probably want to get rid of the .wav part in the middle of the file:

```
mv "$file" "zzz - ${file%.wav} - copied $DATE.wav"
```

The `${var%string}` returns the value of $var with string removed from the end of it if present. You can find more about this looking for bash string manipulation.

Comment: This went above and beyond the scope of my question, which really helped me. I just tested this and it all works very well. Thank you.